# Перенос строки в QPushButton

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4

Текст в `QPushButton` не помещается полностью. Как сделать, чтоб он переносился (например, чтоб был в 2 рядах) и помещался полностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенос текста в `QPushButton`:

```
QPushButton button;
button->setText("Multiline\nText");
```

Узнать помещается ли текст в кнопке можно, например, с помощью следующей конструкции:

```
if (button->fontMetrics().elidedText(button->text(), Qt::ElideMiddle, button->geometry().width()) != button->text())
{
    // Текст не помещается.
}
```

Но почему-то это получается не совсем точно. Где-то, кажется, ещё есть рамки при выводе (вероятно, padding в стилях).

Comment: каким методом можно узнать помещается текст на кнопке или нет?

Comment: @Тарас Обновил ответ.

Comment: а по высоте не определяется,помещается ли текст в кнопке или нет. Исправте пожалуста.